# How to add sequential numbers to a list of tuples

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a question which looks quite simple, but I could not find an acceptable answer as yet. It looks that variations of it have already been asked here several times, but none of the answers was helpful to me.

Here it is:

I have a lists of tuples, as follows:

```
reflist = [("Author1", 1900, "Some reference"), ("Author2", 1901, "Another reference"), ("Author3", 1902, "Yet another reference")]
```

What I want is to add a sequential number to each tuple in the list, so that I got:

```
reflist = [(1, "Author1", 1900, "Some reference"), (2, "Author2", 1901, "Another reference"), (3, "Author3", 1902, "Yet another reference")]
```

This looks silly and a list comprehension should do the trick, but I cannot discern just how :-(

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate()` runs over a sequence and generates index, value pairs. You can't merge directly into your tuples - because tuples are immutable, you can't change their length - but one way you could do it is to convert the tuples you have into lists, make the index number a list, concatenate the two lists together, and convert the result to a tuple:

```
reflist2 = [tuple([index+1] + list(ref)) for index, ref in enumerate(reflist)]
```

(I've edited it to index+1 because enumerate starts counting from 0)

Answer (score -1):

```
f = [tuple(list(elem).insert(0, i)) for elem in reflist for in range(len(reflist))]
```

What this list comprehension does is that it tells for each original entry in reflist, it should convert it to a list, then insert a number in some integer list to the 0 position of the list, then convert that list back into a tuple, and put it all together in a ne wlist.

Comment: Invalid syntax in your `for in range` bit. Fixing that for the missing `i`, it doesn't work because `list.insert()` doesn't return anything, so `tuple()` has no parameter, and it throws `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. Even if that was fixed it's a double loop, so it returns each list item as many times as there are items in the list - way too many results.